# Increase tooltip message duration

Tags: bug, user-experience

I just up voted an answer and a tooltip box appeared next to it, which I *think* said "You haven't voted on ..." or something along those lines.

I literally couldn't read it, but am really interested in what it has to say. I would imagine it was on screen for around 1 second, and it would be a little more user friendly if it was on screen for closer to 5 seconds, or until the cross is clicked to close it.

Its the second time in the last week I've failed to read whatever warning this, I'm a native English speaker and perhaps it could do with someone from UX just taking a look at it.

Comment: This dialog reminds us to vote on questions.

Comment: It says "_You have't voted on a question in a while, questions needs votes too!_"

Comment: That's fair enough... I think I feel like [this guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question "the man"), its hard upvoting questions sometimes, the spectrum of different programming questions is so large, its rare that I see a question that strikes a cord with me. Anyway... I still maintain that its hard to read and wouldn't hurt being on screen a little longer than it is!